# Почему дублируются файлы в vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Редактор]
[image: list1]
[image: list2]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при выборе в vs code из src будь то картинки, скрипты, вообще какие-либо файлы при автозаполнении редактор выдает все в удвоенном количестве, подозреваю может из за какого либо плагина?

Comment: Какие у вас установлены расширения?

Comment: @MoloF у вас с этим все нормально? У меня такая же проблема как у автора вопроса и я думал, что у всех так

Answer (score 1):

У тебя установлены  All Autocomplete и Path Autocomplete. Они оба выполняют поиск файлов, одновременно!, соответственно тебе и показывает по два варианта каждого найденного файла.
Выключи или удали один из них, перезагрузи vs code, вернее он сам предложит его перезагрузить, и всё - проблема исчезнет.